# Displaying a list of filtered products by the user input gatsbyJS + Firebase

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a product catalog with gatsby and firebase, and I want to display a list of products 
according to the product category that the user chooses. I'd fetch all products add pagination and now I need a filter menu or select, so I tried this to implement a filter..before that everything was going fine...

```
imports
...

// query

export const data = graphql`
  query data($skip:Int!, $limit:Int!) {
   products: allProducts(
     skip: $skip, 
     limit: $limit, 
     sort: {fields: id, order: ASC}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        slug
        categories
        model
        previewImg
        description
        category
      }
    }
  }
}
`

//component

class ProductsSectionTemplate extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
        this.state={
          products:[],
          product:''
        }
     }

     handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
     };
     handleChangeProduct = event => {
        this.setState({ product: event.target.value });
     };

     getUnique(arr, comp) {
       const unique = arr
          //store the comparison values in array
         .map(e => e[comp])

         // store the keys of the unique objects
         .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

         // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
         .filter(e => arr[e])

         .map(e => arr[e]);

        return unique;

      }
      componentDidMount(){
        const products = data.products.edges.map( product => ({
          ...product.node,
           previewImg: product.node.previewImg,
           category:product.node.category
        }))

        this.setState({
          products: products
        })
      }

   render(){
      const { pageContext} = this.props
      const products = this.state.products
      const product = this.state.product
      const { currentPage, numPages } = pageContext
      const isFirst = currentPage === 1
      const isLast = currentPage === numPages
      const prevPage = currentPage - 1 === 1 ? "/" : (currentPage - 1).toString()
      const nextPage = (currentPage + 1).toString()

      const uniqueProduct = this.getUnique(this.state.products, "category");
      const filterDropdown = products.filter( result => result.category === product );

     return(
       <Layout>
         <h1>Productos</h1>
         <select
              value={this.state.product}
              onChange={this.handleChangeProduct}
            >
              {uniqueProduct.map(product => (
                  <option key={product.id} value={product.category}>{product.category}</option>
              ))}
         </select>
          <ProductsSection products={filterDropdown}/>
          {!isFirst && (
            <Link to={`/products/${prevPage}`} rel="prev">
              ← Previous Page
            </Link>
          )}
          {Array.from({ length: numPages }, (_, i) => (
            <Link key={`pagination-number${i + 1}`} to={`/products/${i === 0 ? "" : i + 1}`}>
              {i + 1}
            </Link>
          ))}
          {!isLast && (
            <Link to={`/products/${nextPage}`} rel="next">
              Next Page →
            </Link>
          )}
       </Layout>
     )
   }
}

...
```

what I get of this is an error that says:

## TypeError: Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined

ProductsSectionTemplate.componentDidMount

```
 }
  59 | componentDidMount(){
> 60 |   const products = data.products.edges.map( product => ({
  61 |     ...product.node,
  62 |      previewImg: product.node.previewImg,
  63 |      category:product.node.category
```

here is the gatsby-node.js file:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({graphql, actions}) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const products = await graphql(`
     {
      allProducts (sort: {fields: id, order: ASC}, limit: 100){
        edges {
          node {
            id
            slug
            model
            description
            categories
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) throw result.errors;

    const productNodes = result.data.allProducts.edges;

    return productNodes.map( edge =>{
      return {
        ...edge.node
      }
    })
  })

  const productsPerPage = 6
  const numPages = Math.ceil(products.length / productsPerPage);

  Array.from({length:numPages}).forEach((_, i)=>{
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? '/products' : `/products/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/ProductsSectionTemplate.js'),
      context: {
        products,
        limit:productsPerPage,
        skip: i * productsPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      }
    });
  })

  products.forEach( product => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${product.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/singleProduct.js'),
      context: {
        product
      }
    });
  });
}
```

can anybody help me to get this working right..?

Thanks in advice, regards

Answer (score 0):

One reason your query might come back as undefined could be that your graphQL variables do not contain any values.

You can only use variables inside your graphQL with page queries. For this you need to define context variables inside your gatsby-node.js as documented in the [official documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query):

```js
posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
  createPage({
    path: node.fields.slug,
    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
    // values in the context object are passed in as variables to page queries
    context: {
      title: node.passThisVariable, 
    },
  })
})
```

If this does not answer your question, edit your question with your `gatsby-node.js` code.

Comment: I think that what I need to do is assign the request value to this.state.products.

Comment: If I console.log(data.products.edges) inside the render function logs the data... so, does componentDidMount() function have anything to do in it? or is there a scope problem?

Comment: I log the data in componentDidMount and it logs a number 242000616...what it means this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using hooks:

```
const ProductsSectionTemplate = ({ data }) => {

  const [products, setProducts ] = useState([])
  const [product, setProduct ] = useState('')


   function handleChangeProduct (e) {
      setProduct(e.target.value);

   };

  function getUnique(arr, comp) {
    const unique = arr
      //store the comparison values in array
      .map(e => e[comp])

      // store the keys of the unique objects
      .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

      // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
      .filter(e => arr[e])

      .map(e => arr[e]);

    return unique;
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    const productsList = data.products.edges.map( product => ({
      ...product.node,
       previewImg: product.node.previewImg,
       category:product.node.category,
       categories:product.node.categories
    }))
    setProducts(productsList)
  },[data])

  const uniqueProduct = getUnique(products, 'category')

  const filterDropdown = products.filter(result => result.category === product)

  return(
    <Layout>

      <h1>Productos</h1>

        <h4 className="title">Filtrar Productos:</h4>
        <div className="filters">
         {uniqueProduct.map(product => (    
             <label key={product.id}>
                <input
                      className='filters-available-size'
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={product.category}
                      onChange={handleChangeProduct}
                   />
                   <span className="checkmark">
                       {product.category}
                   </span>
             </label>
          ))}
        </div>

        {!!filterDropdown.length && (
          <div>
             <p>{product}</p>
             <ProductsSection products={filterDropdown}/>
          </div>

        )}
        {!!products.length && !filterDropdown.length && (
          <div>
            <p>Categorias</p>
            <ProductsSection products={uniqueProduct}/>
          </div>
        )}

    </Layout>
  )
}
```

and also changed the query to just:

```
export const data = graphql`
  {
    products: allProducts{
     edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          categories
          model
          previewImg
          description
          category
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: I still have to improve the script, because when I click to see a product and I want to return to the list of products that I filtered, I have to filter again, I guess it is because the route does not change, and the way that DOM loads in the browser...so I need to save the last filtered list in the state? I will be investigating about it ... I suspect that maybe using localStorage .. but I don't know ..maybe this is a question for another post.